# CSS Flexbox: Is it possible to align paragraphs in the following setup?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Before we start: Note that I have used the unprefixed spec flexbox syntax, so to see the flexbox working, please look at the examples in Chrome (or Firefox should probably work, too).

Take the following example, a simple grid system with three columns:

```css
/**
 * Makeshift reset
 */
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html { box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }

/**
 * The Grid
 */
.grid {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  margin-left: -24px;
}

/* Clearfix */
.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 24px;
  width: 33.333%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="column">
        <h2>Some Headline</h2>
        <p>Left column</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
        <h2>Short</h2>
        <p>Center column</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
        <h2>Another random headline</h2>
        <p>Right column</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since the column's content is of different height, the columns aren't equal height – standard CSS problem.

Now with Flexbox, thats rather easy to solve by adding `display: flex;` to the grid:

```
.grid {
  display: flex;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  margin-left: -24px;
}
```

```css
/**
 * Makeshift reset
 */
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html { box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }

/**
 * The Grid
 */
.grid {
  display: flex;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  margin-left: -24px;
}

/* Clearfix */
.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 24px;
  width: 33.333%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="column">
        <h2>Some Headline</h2>
        <p>Left column</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
        <h2>Short</h2>
        <p>Center column</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
        <h2>Another random headline</h2>
        <p>Right column</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the column height is equal, but the first line of the paragraphs is not aligned, so it still looks a bit broken.

Of course I've tried this myself and ran into various problems:

- When adding `display:flex` to `.grid`, only the direct children are flex items. That means we have control over `.column`, but not over the content inside the columns.
- When adding `display:flex` to `.column`, we now have control over the column content, but thats not of much use as we have three independent flex items.

The closest I've got was by adding `align-items: flex-end` to `.grid`, but it still looks broken, just a bit different:

```css
/**
 * Makeshift reset
 */
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html { box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }

/**
 * The Grid
 */
.grid {
  display: flex;
  align-items:flex-end;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  margin-left: -24px;
}

/* Clearfix */
.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 24px;
  width: 33.333%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="column">
        <h2>Some Headline</h2>
        <p>Left column</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
        <h2>Short</h2>
        <p>Center column</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
        <h2>Another random headline</h2>
        <p>Right<br>column</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding

```css
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
/**
* Makeshift reset
*/
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html { box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }

/**
* The Grid
*/
.grid {
  display: flex;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  margin-left: -24px;
}

/* Clearfix */
.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 24px;
  width: 33.333%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="column">
        <h2>Some Headline</h2>
        <p>Left column</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
        <h2>Short</h2>
        <p>Center column</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
        <h2>Another random headline</h2>
        <p>Right column</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or

```css
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between
}
.column > h2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```css
/**
* Makeshift reset
*/
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html { box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }

/**
* The Grid
*/
.grid {
  display: flex;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  margin-left: -24px;
}

/* Clearfix */
.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 24px;
  width: 33.333%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.column > h2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="column">
        <h2>Some Headline</h2>
        <p>Left column</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
        <h2>Short</h2>
        <p>Center column</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
        <h2>Another random headline</h2>
        <p>Right column</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or

```css
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between
}
.column > h2 {
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```css
/**
* Makeshift reset
*/
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html { box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }

/**
* The Grid
*/
.grid {
  display: flex;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  margin-left: -24px;
}

/* Clearfix */
.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 24px;
  width: 33.333%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.column > h2 {
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="column">
        <h2>Some Headline</h2>
        <p>Left column</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
        <h2>Short</h2>
        <p>Center column</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
        <h2>Another random headline</h2>
        <p>Right column</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: everywhere is the same result and it's not desired result

Comment: @SzymonDziewoński Yes, they all should produce (almost) the same. Maybe I have understood it wrong, which is the desired result?

Comment: I wasnt sure now If I was wrong, but as far I read about issue, he wanted the first column have wrong alignment, and in your examples is the same result

Comment: With your help I am trying to align the start of the paragraphs, so that they all begin on the same line, even with different headlines.